# How to check if any backup policy applied on virtual machine via azure fluent API?

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net

I want check if any backup policy enable for virtual machine currently I am using Azure Management ResourceManager Fluent API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code

1. Create a service principal and assign Contributor role to the sp
2. SDk

```
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute" Version="46.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Management.RecoveryServices.Backup" Version="4.1.5-preview" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.30.1" />
```

3. Code

```
 var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .WithAuthority(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", tenantDomain))
                .Build();
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" };
            var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                     .ExecuteAsync();

            var cred = new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken);

            ComputeManagementClient computeClient = new ComputeManagementClient(cred);
            computeClient.SubscriptionId = subscription;
            RecoveryServicesBackupClient backupClient = new RecoveryServicesBackupClient(cred);
            backupClient.SubscriptionId = subscription;
             foreach (var vm in await computeClient.VirtualMachines.ListAllAsync()) {
                BackupStatusResponse res = await backupClient.BackupStatus.GetAsync(vm.Location, new BackupStatusRequest()
                {
                    ResourceId = vm.Id,
                    ResourceType = "VM"
                });

                Console.WriteLine($"the vm {vm.Name} has been assiocated with backup policy {res.PolicyName}");


            }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply .....Yes Its  very useful for me ....